# Error al conectarme a una BBDD SQL Server con Python

Tags: html, python, sql-server

Estoy tratando de hacer un mini formulario HTML en donde pueda elegir a través de un  entre varias opciones, y enviar el formulario con el resultado escogido.

El formulario está vinculado a una función Lambda que he creado, pero he hecho pruebas enviando una simple lista de números al formulario, y este funciona y envía la eleccíon del usuario a la función Lambda.

El problema que tengo es que el formulario HTML debe mostrar para elegir entre varios registros, los cuales son extraidos de una BBDD SQL Server. Estoy tratando de conectarme a la BBDD con el mismo código con el que me conecté con otra función Lambda, pero me da un error al seleccionar el driver.

El código que utilizo para conectarme a la BBDD es el siguiente:

```
driver = pyodbc.drivers()[0]

# Inicializo una serie de variables que contienen la información necesaria para 
# conectarme a la BBDD.

server = 'xxx'
nombreBBDD = 'xxx'
user = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'


# Conectar con la base de datos
conn = pyodbc.connect('''DRIVER={driver};
                         SERVER={server};
                         DATABASE={nombre};
                         UID={user};
                         PWD={password}'''.format(driver = driver,
                                                  server = server,
                                                  nombre = nombreBBDD,
                                                  user = user,
                                                  password = password))
```

---

He probado a imprimir por pantalla el resultado de pyodbc.drivers(), y me devuelve la siguiente lista:

```
['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
```

---

El **código de mi formulario HTML** es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario HTML</title>
    <style>
      /* Estilos para el formulario (no es importante) */
      form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      label, input, textarea {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }
      label {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      input, textarea {
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      button {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      button:hover {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
      }
      /* ... */
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <header style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Formulario de seleccion</h1>
  </header>

    <form action="aquí va la URL de mi Lambda" method="POST">
      <select name="empresa">
        {% for empresa in empresas %}
        <option value="{{ empresa }}">{{ empresa }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>




</body>

</html>

    <script>
       document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
       event.preventDefault(); // Evitar el envío del formulario por defecto

       // Obtener el valor seleccionado del <select>
       var selectedValue = document.getElementById("empresasSelect").value;

       // Enviar el valor seleccionado a la función Lambda
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open("POST", "aquí va la URL de mi Lambda", true);
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
           // Manejar la respuesta de la función Lambda aquí
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
         }
       };
        var payload = JSON.stringify({ empresaSeleccionada: selectedValue });
        xhr.send(payload);
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

El **código Python completo** es el siguiente:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pyodbc




app = Flask(__name__)

def conectarBBDD():

    # Defino el controlador de la BBDD a la que me quiero conectar.
    driver = pyodbc.drivers()[0]

    # Inicializo una serie de variables que contienen la información necesaria para 
    # conectarme a la BBDD.

    server = 'xxx'
    nombreBBDD = 'xxx'
    user = 'xxx'
    password = 'xxx'


    # Conectar con la base de datos
    conn = pyodbc.connect('''DRIVER={driver};
                             SERVER={server};
                             DATABASE={nombre};
                             UID={user};
                             PWD={password}'''.format(driver = driver,
                                                      server = server,
                                                      nombre = nombreBBDD,
                                                      user = user,
                                                      password = password))


    # Ejecuto una consulta para obtener los datos de la tabla registrados en el día 
    # anterior.

   return conn


   # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   # -----------------------------------------------


def mostrarEmpresasContratos(conn):

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""xxx""")
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    # Cerrar la conexión con la base de datos
    conn.close()

    return results




@app.route('/')
def index():

    conexion = conectarBBDD()
    empresas = mostrarEmpresasContratos(conexion)


    return render_template('formulario.html', empresas = empresas)






if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

El **ERROR** que me aparece es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrá que ver con el lío de las conexiones JDBC que MSSQL cifra por defecto? Si no han respondido y me queda tiempo, intento mirar en un rato...

Comment: Según los mensajes de error, suena a que el ODBC no se puede conectar a la BD. Hice una prueba con tu código en mi entorno con el mismo driver, pero con un viejo SQL Server 2008 y se conectó perfectamente. Verifica que realmente la base de datos esté [aceptando conexiones externas](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+allow+remote+connections). Sugiero esta línea `driver = pyodbc.drivers()[0]` la cambies por la cadena directamente ya que ese orden varía de un equipo a otro.

Comment: Finalmente he probado a crear una Lambda desde la que envío la información de la BBDD al formulario, y otra para recibir la selección del usuario en el formulario y procesarla. Es curioso que la misma configuración en AWS Lambda sí me funcione para conectarme a la BBDD.